# Accessing Android 11 Permission Labels

Tags: android, permissions, android-11

In Android 11 new "One Time" permission where introduced alongside normal permission like "When In Use".

When the user selects "One Time" permission we get the same permission array as "When in Use" we can verify whether the below permission are accepted.

```
Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
```

Is there any sort of differentiation which is available for using that data to be sent to Analytics. So we can track what sort of permission are the users providing.

Comment: I do not think that apps find out about this. After all, it is no different than the user selecting "when in use", using your app for a bit, then revoking the permission via the Settings app.

Comment: I've just posted [kind-of duplicated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63835942/android-11-recognizing-if-my-app-has-record-audio-or-camera-permission-from-br) with some sample feature, which got broken in my app because of this API change. Any suggestions for my case?